# Django ORM "latest" in templates

Tags: django, django-templates, django-orm

I have following code:

```
class Table1(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=128)

class Table2(models.Model):
    name = models.Charfield(max_length=128)
    event = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    table1 = models.ForeignKey(Table1)
```

In template I try to do following:

```
    {{ table1.table2_set.latest__event.name }}
```

What is I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Dunno. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps you mean `{{ table1.table2_set.latest.event.name }}`? In order to use `.latest()` without field name, define [`get_latest_by`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#django.db.models.Options.get_latest_by) in the model `Table2`.

Comment: If I use this code without get_latest_by I get AssertionError:
latest() requires either a field_name parameter or 'get_latest_by' in the model.

Comment: @Ant Yes, Django has no idea about which field you want to use to sort a queryset and get the latest item from it, unless you tell it.

Comment: I got **ValueError at /my/page/
earliest() and latest() require either fields as positional arguments or 'get_latest_by' in the model's Meta.**

Comment: So in the `class Meta:` add `get_latest_by = "yourFieldName"`. Where **yourFieldName** is the name of your field.